# Mapping Object React -> Issue with Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js, marionette, ramda.js

Converting a handlebars/ marionette project into React.

Need to map an array of two objects:

```
[{COAL: 462, GAS: 400, MIXED: 230, OIL: 288, TOTAL: 1380}, {COAL: 0, GAS: 0, MIXED: 0, OIL: 0, TOTAL: 0}]
```

This is how I'm currently doing that:

```
<tr className="Total">
    <td className="tableBoldBorder  hide">Total</td>
    {props.totals.map(totals =>
        R.values(totals).map(totals => (
            <td className="{{@key}}Column">{formatNumberValues(totals)}</td>
        ))
        )}
</tr>
```

All well and good. Observe @key though, that is still a handlebars function. Essentially, I want the classname to coincide with the column being rendered ie. COALColumn -> 462, GASColumn -> 400 etc.

The issue is, I have lost the keys during the mapping process. R.values(totals).map gives the following output:

```
[[462, 400, 230, 288, 1380], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Is there anyway to get access to the keys to allow for dynamic, mapped classNames?

Thanks for reading!

edit:

What I'm currently getting:

[image]

Result I want:

[image]

The className "TOTALColumn" will render a border on that specific column. Hard coding this, as I've done in the attached image, is not an option.

Comment: How many rows/cells do you want? It would really help to have an example of the resulting row (or rows) as you'd like it to appear.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of `Object.values` to map over the keys:

```
<tr className="Total">
  <td className="tableBoldBorder  hide">Total</td>
  {props.totals.map(totals =>
    Object.keys(totals).map(key => (
      <td className={`${key}Column`}>{formatNumberValues(totals[key])}</td>
    ))
  )}
</tr>
```

Comment: Wow. Quick and accurate response! Object.keys has plenty of browser support also! Thanks!

Comment: @PaulPhillips - `Object.keys` was added in ES5 and is supported by all modern browsers (you could polyfill it for IE8 if you had to, as well). There's also a newer way to do this with `Object.entries`: `Object.entries(totals).map(([key, value]) => /*...use key for the key and value for the value*/)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Object.entries` is what you looking for?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a vague pointer in the direction of an answer.

Comment: true, sorry about that :(